# Name of the Samsung Galaxy end of charger

Tags: usb, charger

This is probably a weird question to ask but I am looking for the end "jack" of the Samsung Galaxy S3, S4 etc charger name. Is not the USB side of the cable, is the actual bit which goes inside the phone. I looked online with various names and I cannot find the name for it. I know the headphones side is called "jack" but not the charger bit apparently.

Anyone willing to help me please?

Thank you.

Comment: If I posted in the incorrect section I apologise, could you direct me to where to post this please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this has everything to do with electronic design because you can't spec a part if you don't know what to call it.

I believe the part you are looking for is a [Female Micro B USB connector](http://www.adafruit.com/products/1829?gclid=CJ2-4679mcYCFVaPHwodNb0A8Q), which apparently are pretty cheap.

:EDIT:

I re-read your question and I'm not entirely clear on what aspect of the charging cable you're talking about. The Samsung charger uses a base, which is the 110VAC to a [Type A Female USB connector](http://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/TE-Connectivity/1-292303-6/?qs=sGAEpiMZZMulM8LPOQ%252byk1Q0DdRGpEPvTs6btfd8UNoA%252b5enuA1s1A%3d%3d).

The cable has a [Type A Male USB connector](http://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Molex/48037-0001/?qs=sGAEpiMZZMulM8LPOQ%252bykxKOk52KZ3dlxC6teGLJgTk%3d) on one end and a [Male Micro B USB connector](http://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Molex/105017-0001/?qs=sGAEpiMZZMulM8LPOQ%252bykxkHE97o%2fWJn1YkS%2fQp33f4%3d) on the other end.

[Here's a link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB#Standard_connectors) to the USB connector sizes, too.

Comment: Edited for a little more content because I wasn't sure what part you were looking for exactly; if this answers your question please accept it :D

Comment: Yes you're right, I was actually looking for the Male A but Female B gave me an idea of what to call this thing! Lol Spot on mate much appreciated!

Comment: Awesome, glad to help!